# SQLite database fetch code does not work synchronously therefore I cant update my component using set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, es6-promise

A am trying to fetch data from SQLite database and while loading the page it will render into my Flat list in react native. But the problem is the data fetch take some time, so my flat list does not update by using the `setstate()` method Because setstate method executes before getting data from the database. I am using async await and also promises but I can't find a solution.

I am trying async await, promise, etc..

```
 async componentDidMount()  
 {
  const p=await this.datafun();

  this.setState({
  fdata:[...p],
  flag:false
    })
 }

    datafun()
 {
  var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
  const db= SQLite.openDatabase({name :'anand.db', createFromLocation : 1});
  db.transaction(  function (txn) {
  txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM my_conyact ', [],   function (tx, res) {
  for (let i = 0; i <res.rows.length; ++i) 
  {
  this.state.fdata=[...this.state.fdata,{ UNIT: res.rows.item(i).column5 }];
  }
  }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));

return new Promise((resolve)=>{
  resolve(this.state.fdata);
})
 }
```

I want to execute the `setstate()` method after fetching data from the database and value return to the 'const p'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datafun() {

    var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
    const db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: 'anand.db', createFromLocation: 1 });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction(function (txn) {
        txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM my_conyact ', [], function (tx, res) {
          resolve(res);
        });
      })
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.datafun().then((dt) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < dt.rows.length; ++i) {
        this.state.fdata = [...this.state.fdata, { UNIT: dt.rows.item(i).column5 }]
      }

      this.setState(
        {
          fdata: [...this.state.fdata],
          flag: false,
        }
      )

    })
  }
```

Finaly i got it !!!

Answer (score 0):

You were heading the good way but there some mistake in how to use promise. You do return a promise but you do not execute the function in the promise.

Moreover I am not sure that casting componentDidMount in async is recommended the syntax with seems more recommended here an idea to what it may look like

```
 componentDidMount()  
 {
    this.datafun().then(function(data) {
    this.setState({
        // HERE update your state
    })
  })
 }

    datafun()
 {
  var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
  const db= SQLite.openDatabase({name :'anand.db', createFromLocation : 1});

  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  db.transaction(  function (txn) {
    txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM my_conyact ', [],   function (tx, res) {
      resolve(res);
     }); 
    })
    })
 }
```